# iMac boot from linux partition on external drive

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, efi

I have the following "setup:"

```
iMac (no internal drive/dead) --------- (Firewire) ------- [[MAC OS X]]
|
|
|
|
(USB)
|
|
|
|
[[MISC STORAGE PARTITION] [MISC STORAGE PARTITION] [EXT2 UBUNTU PARTITION]]
```

I routinely use the firewire drive to boot MAC OS X.

However, I would like to boot from the linux partition of the USB drive. This linux partition had linux installed on it from a live cd, and during that process, I told the installer to install GRUB on the usb drive (which happened to be /dev/sdd).

My question is, how do I get this disk to show up during the iMac option-boot? Currently, only the firewire MAC OS X option shows up. I have read about rEFIT, but that appears to install it to the Mac OS X disk (would that still work?)...

Also mentioned was installing rEFIT to the internal EFI system partition, but I don't know if that is wise.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most useful link I have found for Ubuntu on an iMac using USB.

I just swapped Karmic for Lucid. You boot holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key. I used a 16 GB SanDisk stick for Ubuntu and never had to touch my iMac's hard drive.

[Installation of Ubuntu Karmic Koala for a MacBook Pro 3,1 on a USB stick | Linux on your Apple Mac](http://mac.linux.be/content/installation-ubuntu-karmic-koala-macbook-pro-31-usb-stick)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any good way to install Linux on Mac using Boot Camp, but you can tell Boot Camp to create a Windows entry and then install Linux to it.

I don't think you can rescue it at this point, so you might need to redo the process.

[(Source)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=678542)

If you install it using Boot Camp as a Windows partition, then you should be good. This isn't exactly a direct answer to your question, but I don't know what else you can do at this point... you have to trick the Mac to do anything not officially supported, that's kinda how it is.

Comment: The problem is that boot camp think it needs an internal drive to make a "windows" partition. There is absolutely no problem with booting Mac OSX from the firewire drive, this is how I routinely use my computer since the internal drive died.

Comment: My issue is, that if the option-boot lets me choose a firewire drive containing Mac OS X, why wouldn't it let me choose a a USB drive that contains Linux? I think it is probably something to do with there being multiple partitions on the disk containing linux.