# Boot Camp on external hard-drive partition?

Tags: windows, linux, mac, boot-camp

I would like to know if it is possible to boot Windows or Linux on a Mac through BootCamp, or without it, from an external hard-drive so to leave the internal drive completely unaffected. the thread [iMac boot from linux partition on external drive](https://superuser.com/questions/266135/imac-boot-from-linux-partition-on-external-drive) was not enough clear to me.